# How do I prerender a Svelte component and manually hydrate it with a JS file?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

From the SvelteKit docs:

> By default, SvelteKit will render (or prerender) any component first on the server and send it to the client as HTML. It will then render the component again in the browser to make it interactive in a process called hydration.

I tried digging in the Svelte compiler, but it's not very well documented and clearly not intended to be used outside of vite/rollup etc.

For my use case I want to 1) render a single Svelte component as a static HTML (SSR) and 2) generate a JS file that I can include in my page to hydrate the generated HTML.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your usecase exactly? This sounds like you're looking for SSG (static site _generation_) with the [static adapter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static).

Comment: The use case is a widget like google maps, which I want to initialize dynamically. I ended up using Svelte without Kit.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible solution. If your aim is to use this widget in a non-Svelte application you might be interested in [compiling to custom elements](https://svelte.dev/docs/custom-elements-api) (WebComponents).

Comment: @Nikolay Dyankov how did you set this up, is there a repo I can reference?  Currently facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Fasteroid The compiler already does all of the work for you. Just place the div#app element in your website and include the generated JS whenever you want to init (or hydrate) the component.

Comment: But what if I want to manually hydrate, for instance, if I *don't* want certain prerendered content overwritten?

Comment: @Fasteroid I manually hydrate by manually loading the script file. I don't know what you mean by prerendered content overwritten.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov oh wait I get it now, you mean to include a script in `app.html`... that makes sense now.  Somehow took me 4 days to guess that.  Rookie mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the plain Svelte compiler, without SvelteKit.

If you want to use this compiled component in a non-Svelte application you might be interested in [compiling to custom elements](https://svelte.dev/docs/custom-elements-api) (WebComponents).

Comment: Downvoted since there isn't enough information here for a novice to replicate OP's solution.  I really wish I could retract my bounty.